# Use that goodn't meme

Tags: code-golf, string

There is currently a meme on the internet that consist of taking a sentence, reverse the meaning and adding `n't` at the end. For example, `I am small` becomes `I am talln't`

### Challenge

For the sake of the challenge, we'll simplify this : Your task will be to detect whenever there is a negation in a sentence, and replace it with the 'positive' one with `n't` added at the end. There will be some tricky parts that will be explained in the rules.

### Rules

- You have to take a *String* as *input*, and return a *String* as *output*.
- Input will be a sentence **in lowercase**, with only `.` and `,` as punctuation marks.
- You have to replace any `no <any_word>` or `not <any_word>` with `<any_word>n't`.
- `no`/`not` have to be a word and **not** a substring : you don't have to change anything in `none of those`
- If the word already finish with a `n`, you have to replace `n't` with `'t` : `no plan` become `plan't` and **not** `plann't`
- When `no` or `not` isn't followed by any word, a punctuation mark  or another `no`/`not`, you have to replace it with **`yesn't`**.
- compound words count as one word. so even if `no-op` contain the substring `no`, it doesn't contain the **word** no. So the result will be `no-op` and **not** `-opn't`.
- You do not have to worry about grammar errors. For example, `there is no way` will result to `there is wayn't`.
- No standard loopholes allowed.
- This is [codegolf](/questions/tagged/codegolf), so the shortest code wins.

There are some examples, even if this challenge looks clearn't for now.

### Examples

> **Input :** i love codegolfing, but i do not like short programs.
>   does this sentence makes sense ... of course no.
>   **Output :** i love codegolfing, but i do liken't short programs.
>   does this sentence makes sense ... of course yesn't.
>
> **Input** : you are not invited. get out.
>   **Output** : you are invitedn't. get out.
>
> **Input** : i am not ok, i have no plan and i have no gunn
>   **Output** : i am okn't, i have plan't and i have gunn't
>
> **Input** : oh no no no i refuse.
>   **Output** : oh yesn't yesn't in't refuse.
>
> **Input** : oh no no no, i refuse.
>   **Output** : oh yesn't yesn't yesn't, i refuse.
>
> **Input** : i cannot believe this, you can't codegolf.
>   **Output** : i cannot believe this, you can't codegolf.
>
> **Input** : oh no ... he did it again.
>   **Output** : oh yesn't ... he did it again.
>
> **Input** : nn't is not a word, kevin. so this is not nn't.
>   **Output** : nn't is an't word, kevin. so this is nn'tn't.
>
> **Input** : is it not clearn't for everyone
>   **Output** : is this clearn'tn't for everyone
>
> **Input** : this is non't sense ...
>   **Output** : this is non't sense ...

Comment: In the introduction, shouldn't `I am small` become `I am bign't`?

Comment: One point says "Input willl be [...] only with only . and ,".  Another refers to "no-op".  But that contains a "-".  So is "-" allowed or not?

Comment: Should `no n` result in `nn't` or `n't`?

Comment: `no n` sould result in `n't` because the 'word' `n` finish with a `n`.

Comment: @Soaku small, tall, big, tiny, large, long, short etc. are all used interchangeably. It doesn't _really_ matter for the sake of the question. But the most logical antonym for small would be big, yes.

Answer (score 5):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language), <s>86</s> <s>70</s> 65 bytes

```
T`-'`L
\bnot?\s+(?!not?\b)(\w+?)n?\b
$1n't
\bnot?\b
yesn't
T`L`-'
```

-16 bytes thanks to *@Neil*.
-5 bytes thanks to *@ovs*.

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##XVFBisMwDLz7FVpYaJcmgb6gH@ixxx7qJEpi4krBdlLy@qzkbnfLgsHSSDMa2QGTI3vctsut3N3O5loTp9M1HvanjxzVX/vr43D6IgnN55F26dVTmxWj5pfbWcjbRgwxWWptaMEzTwN7jGC95we2lXECLggNt9iz7xz1BdRzAgctgyiCdyNCHDgkmAL3wd5jJTXRSIOLEJESUoNwtyPmNCJUVQXciegcJCOuzMoz2IBZ0dHiksyGHhPwnNSEvecSj4VMHuyinTB5SyDW36B@JgLDg8bP4yBgN0es3tHiDXbQWFLxGr1DkVHfBagjKezS7@4vBXU/ILROBiewvXVUGdI3zRvLIVaelbvkKZeeqGIPDm0BIy7Cgsjwx0mgnWIoqq7mjUcblN1xALEWVib8N@X5onmSOjO6n3rJe5L5sSCJfnwpwd2uNZaRvwE)

**Explanation:**

```
T`-'`L             # Replace all "-" with "A" and all "'" with "B" to store them

\bnot?             # Then replace the word "no" or "not",
 \s+               #  followed by 1 or more whitespaces,
 (?!not?\b)(\w+?)  #  followed by a word/letter that is not "not" or "no"
 n?\b              #  minus a single trailing "n" if there are any
$1                 # with: the word/letter
 n't               #  appended with "n't"

\bnot?\b           # Then replace any remaining loose "no" or "not"
yesn't             # with "yesn't"

T`L`-'             # And finally replace all "A" with "-" and all "B" with "'" again
```

Comment: I think [this](https://tio.run/##K0otycxLNPyvquGe8D8vv8ReQSOmXFuTS8UwT72EKw9MgDBQhqsytRjI/v8/I7UoVSGzWAEkqwAA) shouldn't be the case

Comment: @DeadPossum Yeah, thought about that myself just yet and have already asked OP if "nn't" is possible in the input.

Comment: [This](https://tio.run/##K0otycxLNPyvquGe8D8vv8ReQSOmXFuTS8UwT72EKw9MgDBQhqsytRjI/v8/P0MhLx@KMhWKUtNKi1P1AA) is strange too

Comment: @DeadPossum Ah, that's indeed a bug in my code. Will try to fix it. Thanks for noticing.

Comment: [no non should be non't](https://tio.run/##K0otycxLNPyvquGe8D8vT72Eq44rJikvv8ReQUPDXjEvXzOmXFuTS8UQJAWWB2GICq7K1GKIDpDE//95@Qp5@XkA) . Don't hate me, I'm just interested in retina ._.

Comment: @DeadPossum `no non`, `no-op`, and `no nn't` are some annoying edge cases.. But I think everything is fixed now (and my byte-count is doubled XD)

Comment: I think I've got it down to [70 bytes](https://tio.run/##XVDRasMwDHz3V2hQaLOlgbIP2A/0sY99qJMoiYkrBdtJKezfM8mlWxkYbN1JdycHTI7sYV1Pl/32cjTnmjh9nePH7ustv@pid769Fzv6lrsozOaw@aRtejbW5o5R69PlKArrSgwxWWptaMEzTwN7jGC95xu2lXECLggNt9iz7xz1JdRzAgctgyiCdyNCHDgkmAL3wV5jJZxopMFFiEgJqUG42hFzGRGqqgLuRHQOUhFX5s4z2IBZ0dHiknhDjwl4ThrCXjPFYynOg120EyZvCST6C9TPRGB40PfjOAjYzRGrV7R8gR00llS8Ru9QZDR3CZpIiG363f2poOkHhNaJcQLbW0eVIf3TvLEcYp2zcu95ytQDVezGoS1hxEWmIDL8zSTQTgkUVVfrxqMNOt1xAIkW7kz4z@Xxo9lJkxndT7PkPclk4gc "Retina – Try It Online").

Comment: @Neil Thanks. Nice approach with the separated captured `(n|(\w))`.

Comment: `L` here is a shorthand for `A-Z`, saving 2 bytes over ``T`-'`AB`` and vice versa.

Comment: @Neil Ah ok, thanks for explaining. TIL. :) Not too familiar with Retina's builtins yet.

Comment: @DeadPossum [Punctuate it properly](https://tio.run/##K0otycxLNPyvquGe8D8vv8ReQSOmXFuTS8UwT72EKw9MgDBQhqsytRjI/v8/P0MhL18HivUUMhWKUtNKi1P1AA)

Comment: @ovs It gives the incorrect result for "_i am not ok, i have no plan and i have no gunn_" (incorrect for any "not/no" followed by a word that ends in an "n").

Comment: @ovs Umm, all `n't` are now prepending the words instead of appending. EDIT: Changing the `*` to `+` seems to work though (I think).

Comment: I really should have looked closer. I think this fails on `no n` now. The output should be `n't` but the program outputs `nn't`

Comment: @ovs Hmm, I figured it was supposed to be `nn't`. I'll ask OP to verify what to do with it.

Answer (score 4):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>208</s> <s>123</s> <s>113</s> 146 bytes

```python
lambda s:re.sub(r"\bnot?\b(?!['-])(\s(?!not?(\b)(?!['-]))([\w'-]+))?",lambda m:(m.group(3)or"yes")+"n't"[(m.group(3)or'')[-1:]=='n':],s)
import re
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fVFNb8IwDL3vV3i5pBEl0rYbEuJP7NZySKnbRrR2laQgfj1LCkNU@5AiJbbfe352xkvomN6vzba89maoagN@41D7qcqcKCvisCurbPdayPVeZaWPz5TLykp9Z1VWlOf4WCm1E/ldZdhkg24dT2P2odiJC3qhVoJkEMWiIqUq1m@b/XYrSW72uVcvdhjZBXB4HZ2lAE0mLfR8QjhwjS33jaU2h2oKYKFmiIagt0cE3yXe6Lh1ZvA61tBD6KwHjxSQDgiDOeIcegStNXATRScXI2It1cuj44UnMA5ncUsnG7DW0GIAnsICaMEMM4qPefTTmVMiwdgbAkP1U6qdiJ6Z3KXs7dg4bjN51H8A8l8RwsLBUGpeYW8xtknT5pDMx4IMj41p8cS66abxO4TaRo8BTGssLVCfaXHxECchE@81j/8DfmAksVxEC/eUeLNAop/Z1Tkc8RR9gOfbx92rCbkwl0phLh16NC4JNewgrsBdmPAZGhY2H18v1PUL)

Lost a bunch of bytes because of words ending in `n't` or `n`. Either or is shorter, but handling both was longer.

Answer (score 2):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 95 bytes

```javascript
s=>s.replace(/\bnot?\b( (?!not?\b)(['\w-]*(\w)))?/g,(a,b,s,t)=>(s||'yes')+(t=='n'?'':'n')+"'t")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##pVTBbuIwEL3zFbO9xKaue@8q5VZpT/sBpVKdZEi8BBvZDgip/86OHbKQUCSkRVEcM2/e8zyP/UftlC@d3oYnYys8vuVHn7966XDbqhLZ87IwNiyWBQO2@NF/cvaeLfdPH3O23HPOF8@1YEoUwovA81fmv76yA/qMP7KQ55nJFln2QgN/fMjCAz/@nH3OZkC/X2bbBXgBDa3dIZSkX9t2pU0toKCIhsoCSUKr1wi@sS7A1tnaqY2XFEMPodEePJqApkTYqDWmqUeQUoJdEWnnaGasTJK/u3CHZtQzWfg/SbKAOOS41IPtQDlMVWmz0wErCTUGsF2YrHCAnmCR64yc@Kc2idGuBU0atYsCQBtoQJnq4q@6M2bqA@XaNbH/S415VPxFZkzLwljUNpGwfzQ4XHUeJxUQpDdhGHR8DdBbbOJuun64xE9sKZWJthTYaqQy4s6J5GuZKhw2/6o17s77pobYBA1Cpck9MrFW2tys41vsiNMk23zaXQV76yoBa9wRDrztW/EUNanZRkJDclr0zVwKXvdpjIXEW7aoXCRYWQfkhjtYgxPDTodigF6hR9TnRacjNpycMeUt0Of5Yhr4mJzzpZHz/ovuImBe0HVEV1FpjbctytbW7F3RARfwxhTv33lefHB@/As)

Thank Rick Hitchcock for 2 bytes

Answer (score 2):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), <s>75</s> <s>73</s> 50 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

```
ä§▀t9lJ₧5M#|+4╖¼├n▌ ·=┌«∙£╣▀K╖¥y▐▲·(■◄╙→á╣ó•ô╓╢Θ₧○
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=8415df74396c4a9e354d237c2b34b7acc36edd20fa3ddaaef99cb9df4bb79d79de1efa28fe11d31aa0b9a20793d6b6e99e09&i=oh+no+...+he+did+it+again.%0Ai+love+codegolfing,+but+i+do+not+like+short+programs.+does+this+sentence+makes+sense+...+of+course+no.%0Ayou+are+not+invited.+get+out.%0Ai+am+not+ok,+i+have+no+plan+and+i+have+no+gunn%0Aoh+no+no+no+i+refuse.%0Aoh+no+no+no,+i+refuse.%0Ai+cannot+believe+this,+you+can%27t+codegolf.%0Aoh+no+...+he+did+it+again.%0Ann%27t+is+not+a+word,+kevin.+so+this+is+not+nn%27t.%0Ais+it+not+clearn%27t+for+everyone%0Athis+is+non%27t+sense+...%0Ayes-no+maybe-so%0Aop-no+no-op%0Atrailing+space+no+%0Ano+non&a=1&m=2)

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 72 bytes

```
F=_r"%bnot?%s+(?!not?%b)(%w+?)n?%b|%bnot?%b(?!['-])",@Y=Y||"yes"Y+"n't"}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dU/BaoQwEL33K6ahokGbHyiLPe21ZymlRB11dt2MJLFlwX67TUSWHrYwhzfzHm/eO@nJr@vx8GlFUhv2ZeLyrHzcUC2z5DsvpQlw2dk6kO/p84cUxWt1qJZFXNGJKhcm9eJnfXpTU3bMBMHIXwgNt9jz2JHpC6hnDwQtQzCCkc4IbmDrYbLcW31xKnDowA/kwKHxaBqEiz7jtjoEpRRwF0xnGzbDSkj58rB/5CFc9iGw2M0O/xMU9xUEjTYxXI0jYYgfoxRw5TkSqb/VueMbsw0ILbVAHnSvyfwVbaXCGI4@tzpRsv4C)

Comment: For `"yes-no maybe-so"`, it produces `"yes - mayben't - so"`.

Answer (score 0):

## Java 8, <s>163</s> 136 bytes

```java
s->s.replaceAll("(^|[ ,.])not?(?= *([,.]|$|not?(?=$|[ ,.])))","$1yesn't").replaceAll("(^|[ ,.])not? ([\\w'-]+?)n?(?=$|[ ,.])","$1$2n't")
```

-27 bytes by creating a port of [*@recursive*'s Stax' answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/165773/52210).

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##pVVRb9owEH7frzhZSE1KiLQ9turQfsD60kdgkkmO4GJ8me3QodHfzs5O0tJAu0mTAol9332@@@5sP8qdnFCN5rHcHAstnYPvUpnfnwCU8WhXskC4D0OAB2@VqaBIug@X3vL8M//4cV56VcA9GLiDo5t8dbnFWrP7N60Tkfw4zCDLF6khP02md3CdzHh4GB26iVFnT1ORidHnPTpz5UX6Pgkks/n86WqyGE9Tc8oQ/Udfovvxto2ubpaao@uC3JEqYctpdpnMFiDTNkePzifCUICaUtoSNFG9Jo0OpNb0hGUuMhC9mVe5hIjK9GyKETuEgkqsSK94wQyWjQcFJQGnAlptENyarIfaUmXl1uVsY0K/Vg4cciUM12ErNxiHDiHPc6AVkzaWR4ZiVB@uFFYJ4f7XQm1dBgnuqQFpMeaizE55lgAq9ECNj3H1gM4YGF7tA63kNvLQJuOw13IXaIF7wAArfjJVNca0ObMHbZjzxSGgOdETfACHfjhditaBpn0UWFw1DmO0bGjT7F8q/PWA9ziyv5C0r1PUIPFCmpD4ErVCDjlUJIOgXBGz6YvaFfqf0RfiDSVdI5S8CxTLVPFOGMR8EfGGKerJPue6xlbix1AsAr/5gAnQy4Yz1hYSAE9kyww2uOPVwRG8EngwsQ27AMJkTPtdDzae922w@chWaJQ2EKzIAutp92QwCh0hvfkM8UHi7e6JOQY5zwUYAt4KQXCq8JnIseVi/0eyobFT/JLC7Hi5blz6CVu3cr/EiaO4bwdT3YH/etzHkzS6d3dC@M76mwJ/1Vjwfk/f3B8WXaM93xImL5KA76J42DuP2zycCTUDvTbRCmMQc5OIcdI65vizkdolL@RT4ZqiQCyxFDdiJZXG8gbEuIWnY5HOTR/58/EP)